# What's the best way to approach this simple TicTacToe exercise?

Tags: c#, tic-tac-toe

Everything is working up to here, I just need to create the method that checks whether someone has won.

Any suggestions on how to tackle this problem effectively?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TresEnRaya
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        string[,] tablero;
        bool jugador = true;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            AsignarTags();
            tablero = new string[3, 3];

            button1.Click += clickHandler;
            button2.Click += clickHandler;
            button3.Click += clickHandler;
            button4.Click += clickHandler;
            button5.Click += clickHandler;
            button6.Click += clickHandler;
            button7.Click += clickHandler;
            button8.Click += clickHandler;
            button9.Click += clickHandler;
        }

        private void AsignarTags()
        {
            button1.Tag = new Posicion() { X = 0, Y = 0 };
            button2.Tag = new Posicion() { X = 0, Y = 1 };
            button3.Tag = new Posicion() { X = 0, Y = 2 };
            button4.Tag = new Posicion() { X = 1, Y = 0 };
            button5.Tag = new Posicion() { X = 1, Y = 1 };
            button6.Tag = new Posicion() { X = 1, Y = 2 };
            button7.Tag = new Posicion() { X = 2, Y = 0 };
            button8.Tag = new Posicion() { X = 2, Y = 1 };
            button9.Tag = new Posicion() { X = 2, Y = 2 };
        }

        private void CambiarSimbolo(Button button)
        {
            Posicion objPosicion = (Posicion)button.Tag;

            if (jugador == true)
            {
                tablero[objPosicion.X, objPosicion.Y] = "X";
                button.Text = "X";
                button.Enabled = false;
                jugador = false;
            }
            else
            {
                tablero[objPosicion.X, objPosicion.Y] = "Y";
                button.Text = "Y";
                button.Enabled = false;
                jugador = true;
            }

            VerificarGanador();
        }

        private void VerificarGanador()
        {
            //THE MAGIC GOES HERE. WINGARDIUM LEVIO-Sah
        }

        private void clickHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button myButton = (Button)sender;
            switch (myButton.Name)
            {
                case "button1":
                    CambiarSimbolo(myButton);                    
                    break;

                case "button2":
                    CambiarSimbolo(myButton);
                    break;

                case "button3":
                    CambiarSimbolo(myButton);
                    break;

                case "button4":
                    CambiarSimbolo(myButton);
                    break;

                case "button5":
                    CambiarSimbolo(myButton);
                    break;

                case "button6":
                    CambiarSimbolo(myButton);
                    break;

                case "button7":
                    CambiarSimbolo(myButton);
                    break;

                case "button8":
                    CambiarSimbolo(myButton);
                    break;

                case "button9":
                    CambiarSimbolo(myButton);
                    break;
            }
        }        
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I must admit that I don't really understand your problem. What do you mean with effectifly? Most speed or least code? And besides why would taht even matter here? A TicTacToe-field has 8 Lines which can act as victory conditions, so whats keeping you from just checking all of them one after another (horizontal and vertical cases could be handled with for loops if you want to). Its not like performance or (judging from the posted code) code complexity really matters for such simple cases. On another note: why do you have a switch in clickHandler which does the same thing for all cases?

Comment: You're absolutely correct! Hahahaha, not much sleep last night. :D

Comment: Not really; as stated I could just brute force this things, but I'm curious as to how someone with more experience would handle it.

Comment: I was kidding - mostly. =D You have to admit tho, it would make a decent homework assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most effective way is to know the location of the last X or O placed on the board and check only the directions that include this location. This way, you aren't using brute force to determine if a player has won.

Comment: Good point.  If you know one point then you can reduce the horizontal and vertical comparisons to a single if - (x,y)==((x+1)%3,y)==((x+2)%3,y) || (x,y)==(x,(y+1)%3)==(x,(y+2)%3)  I'm not sure you can abstract the corner to corner condition though.  I actually like @abelenky's solution the best, but this is a good example of thinking about all the data you have available to you when solving a problem or optimising a solution.

Answer (score 3):

I once saw a technique that kept 8 different counters, 1 for each winning direction.

Initialize the counters to zero.
When an **X** is placed, add 1 to the counters for that row, column, and diagonal.
When an **O** is placed, subtract 1 from the counters for the row, column and diagonal.

If any counter reaches 3 or -3, you know you have a winner.
+3 implies that **X** won.
-3 implies that **O** won.

Which counter reached +/-3 tells you which row/column/diagonal won.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there are only 8 possible winning combinations, you could simply check each of them against a set of templates representing winning positions.

In retrospect, I would actually modify your data structure to be an MD-array of numbers rather than strings, with:

> 0 => blank cell
>     1 => player A (X)
>    -1 => player B (O)

You could then just see if the sum across any row, column, or diagonal is equal to either +3 or -3.

Answer (score 1):

Like others have said, brute force is good.

However, I would prefer to list the nodes, rather than loop them, as @Kendrick did.

For example:

```
TicTacVector winVectors[] = 
{
    {"Top Row",    {0,0}, {0,1}, {0,2}},
    {"Middle Row", {1,0}, {1,1}, {1,2}},
    [...]
    {"Diagonal 1", {0,2}, {1,1}, {2,0}}
};
```

*(note: pseudo-code.  Won't actually compile!)*

A bit more intensive in the hand-coding, but I think its also easier to see whats going on.

Comment: I'm sure there is at least one language in which your code is legal and will compile.

Answer (score 1):

Exhaustive search.

Answer (score 0):

For 3x3, I'd brute force it.  There's bound to be a better answer, but there are only 8 winning conditions (vert1,vert2,vert3,horiz1,horiz2,horiz3,cross from top left, cross from bottom left)

```
for x = 0 to 2
   If pos(x,0)==pos(x,1)==pos(X,2)
        return pos(x,0)
for y = 0 to 2
    If pos(0,y)==pos(1,y)==pos(2,y)
        return pos(0,y)
if(pos(0,0)==pos(1,1)==Pos(2,2) || pos(0,2)==pos(1,1)==pos(2,0))
    return pos(1,1)
else
    return null
```

Comment: Yeah I guess I should just brute force it, huh?

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
Button[][] matrix = new[]
{
    new []{ button1, button2, button3 },
    new []{ button4, button5, button6 },
    new []{ button7, button8, button9 },
    new []{ button1, button5, button9 },
    new []{ button3, button5, button7 },
    new []{ button1, button4, button7 },
    new []{ button2, button5, button8 },
    new []{ button3, button6, button9 }
};
var result = matrix.FirstOrDefault(set => 
    set.All(button => button.Text == "X") || 
    set.All(button => button.Text == "Y"));
if(result != null)
{
    string winner = result.First().Text;
}
else
{
    // tie
}
```